# Jupyter notebook and QT Console are calling different version of pandas

Tags: pandas, jupyter

QTConsole is running the latest version of pandas (i.e. 0.18).  However, when I import pandas in Jupyter notebook, it can only import 0.15.  How can I resolve this?

```
**QT Console:**

Jupyter QtConsole 4.2.0
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

import pandas
print pandas.__version__
0.18.0

**Jupyter**

import pandas
print pandas.__version__
0.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have different versions of Python installed via different distributions. If you are using Windows, I recommend uninstalling all Python versions/distributions, rebooting and then only installing one.

If you are using Mac, ensure that you have only one version of Anaconda installed and that it is the version first in your `PATH` if you are using a terminal. It may be that a different version has been installed by for instance homebrew. To check your path do `!echo $PATH` from both of the environments. You should see your anaconda directory early in the path (before `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin`). You can also do `!which python` from both of the environments to see which Python binary is being used.

Comment: I am using Mac and employing anaconda to maintain all libraries and dependencies.

Comment: I still think you have multiple python versions installed. On the mac with Anaconda you will always at least have the system python and Anaconda. You may also have other pythons via for instance Homebrew. I've posted the debugging steps you can follow to check.